# Kubernetes Pods go back and forth from Running State to CrashLoopBackOff State

Tags: kubernetes

I've already asked the question in SOF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77325355/pods-go-back-and-forth-between-state-running-and-state-crashloopbackoff/77325485

But, since it has been pointed out that it's a `sys-admin` question, I ask it also here, hoping to receive expert hints and help

Cluster information:

```
Kubernetes version:
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl version
    Client Version: v1.28.2
    Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
    Server Version: v1.28.2
```

Cloud being used: Contabo Cloud (bare-metal)
Installation method:
followed these steps : https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04/?utm_content=cmp-true
Host OS: Ubuntu 22.04
CNI and version:

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# ls /etc/cni/net.d/
10-flannel.conflist


root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# cat /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist 
{
  "name": "cbr0",
  "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
  "plugins": [
    {
      "type": "flannel",
      "delegate": {
        "hairpinMode": true,
        "isDefaultGateway": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "portmap",
      "capabilities": {
        "portMappings": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

CRI and version:

```
Container Runtime : containerd 

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# cat /etc/containerd/config.toml  | grep version
version = 2
```

OS:

```
Ubuntu 22.04
```

Issue I'm experiencing: pods go back and forth between `Running` State and `CrashLoopBackOff` State

This is the `arango-deployment.yaml` file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VfCjQih5aJUEA4HD9ddsQDrZbLmquWIQ/view?usp=share_link .

And this is the `arango-storage.yaml` file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hqHU_H2Wr5VFrJLwM9GDUHF17b7_CYIG/view?usp=sharing

This is the output of `kubectl describe pod` and `kubectl describe pod` : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kZsYeKxOa5aSppV3IdS6c7-e8dnoLiiB/view?usp=share_link

These are the last lines of the `syslog` of the node containing one of the two crashing pods :

```
Oct 20 15:44:10 k8s-eu-1-worker-1 kubelet[599]: I1020   
15:44:10.594513     599 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="3e618ac247c1392fd6a6d67fad93d187c0dfae4d2cfe77c6a8b244c831dd0852"
Oct 20 15:44:10 k8s-eu-1-worker-1 kubelet[599]: E1020 15:44:10.594988     599 pod_workers.go:1300] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"operator\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 2m40s restarting failed container=operator pod=arango-deployment-operator-5f4d66bd86-4pxkn_default(397bd5c4-2bfc-4ca3-bc7d-bd149932e4b8)\"" pod="default/arango-deployment-operator-5f4d66bd86-4pxkn" podUID="397bd5c4-2bfc-4ca3-bc7d-bd149932e4b8"
Oct 20 15:44:21 k8s-eu-1-worker-1 kubelet[599]: I1020 15:44:21.594619     599 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="3e618ac247c1392fd6a6d67fad93d187c0dfae4d2cfe77c6a8b244c831dd0852"
Oct 20 15:44:21 k8s-eu-1-worker-1 kubelet[599]: E1020 15:44:21.595036     599 pod_workers.go:1300] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"operator\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 2m40s restarting failed container=operator pod=arango-deployment-operator-5f4d66bd86-4pxkn_default(397bd5c4-2bfc-4ca3-bc7d-bd149932e4b8)\"" pod="default/arango-deployment-operator-5f4d66bd86-4pxkn" podUID="397bd5c4-2bfc-4ca3-bc7d-bd149932e4b8"
```

Here the `logs` of each of the pods: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k5g4d7j2uaGQTN7EMgR5Z794KtAg70CD/view?usp=sharing

But the issue is that they continuously go back and forth from `Running` State to `CrashLoopBackOff` State :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
arango-deployment-operator-5f4d66bd86-bgqbd   0/1     Running            8 (5m6s ago)    17m
arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (4m52s ago)   17m

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
arango-deployment-operator-5f4d66bd86-bgqbd   0/1     Running   9 (7s ago)      18m
arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b       0/1     Running   8 (5m53s ago)   18m
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pods

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
arango-deployment-operator-5f4d66bd86-bgqbd   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (2m35s ago)   21m
arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (2m11s ago)   21m
```

This is the output of `kubectl describe pod` of the second pod:

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe arango-storage-operator-
5fcb46574-w2b6b
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b"
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe pod arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b
Name:             arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  arango-storage-operator
Node:             k8s-eu-1-worker-2/zz.zzz.zzz.zzz
Start Time:       Fri, 20 Oct 2023 16:29:06 +0200
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=storage
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Tiller
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=kube-arangodb
                  helm.sh/chart=kube-arangodb-1.2.34
                  pod-template-hash=5fcb46574
                  release=storage
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.0.13
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.13
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574
Containers:
  operator:
    Container ID:  containerd://ce9249b8978d6f902c5162f74e4b4e71d401458587cf0f3a717bd86a75c1b65f
    Image:         arangodb/kube-arangodb:1.2.34
    Image ID:      docker.io/arangodb/kube-arangodb@sha256:a25d031e87ba5b0f3038ce9f346553b69760a3a065fe608727cde188602b59e8
    Port:          8528/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --scope=legacy
      --operator.storage
      --mode.single
      --log.level=debug
      --chaos.allowed=false
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 20 Oct 2023 16:53:53 +0200
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Fri, 20 Oct 2023 16:47:47 +0200
      Finished:     Fri, 20 Oct 2023 16:48:46 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  10
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  2Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      500m
      memory:   1Gi
    Liveness:   http-get https://:8528/health delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get https://:8528/ready delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MY_POD_NAMESPACE:  default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      MY_POD_NAME:       arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b (v1:metadata.name)
      MY_POD_IP:          (v1:status.podIP)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-8bdkv (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-8bdkv:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 5s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 5s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  24m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b to k8s-eu-1-worker-2
  Normal   Pulled     24m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "arangodb/kube-arangodb:1.2.34" in 830ms (830ms including waiting)
  Normal   Pulling    23m (x2 over 24m)     kubelet            Pulling image "arangodb/kube-arangodb:1.2.34"
  Normal   Created    23m (x2 over 24m)     kubelet            Created container operator
  Normal   Started    23m (x2 over 24m)     kubelet            Started container operator
  Normal   Pulled     23m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "arangodb/kube-arangodb:1.2.34" in 1.033s (1.033s including waiting)
  Warning  Unhealthy  23m (x9 over 24m)     kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "https://10.244.0.13:8528/ready": dial tcp 10.244.0.13:8528: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  23m (x6 over 24m)     kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "https://10.244.0.13:8528/health": dial tcp 10.244.0.13:8528: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Killing    23m (x2 over 24m)     kubelet            Container operator failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Pulled     19m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "arangodb/kube-arangodb:1.2.34" in 827ms (827ms including waiting)
  Warning  BackOff    4m48s (x51 over 18m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container operator in pod arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b_default(01f85e27-97bb-45c9-b42b-a2fc2aba0967)
```

`syslog` of the node containing the second pod:

```
 Oct 20 16:59:24 k8s-eu-1-worker-2 kubelet[595]: I1020 16:59:24.180175     595 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="81fad793d8848c7507317c980e37470c06f4e77bb4d8f9b893137dc5fd8f85ef"
Oct 20 16:59:24 k8s-eu-1-worker-2 kubelet[595]: E1020 16:59:24.181224     595 pod_workers.go:1300] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"operator\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=operator pod=arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b_default(01f85e27-97bb-45c9-b42b-a2fc2aba0967)\"" pod="default/arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b" podUID="01f85e27-97bb-45c9-b42b-a2fc2aba0967"
```

What am I doing wrong? How to make the pods keep in "Running" State?

Comment: You need to look into the logs of this specific pod. There you have usually the answer.

Comment: Hi @RaffaelLuthiger I updated the post above with the logs of the two pods: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k5g4d7j2uaGQTN7EMgR5Z794KtAg70CD/view?usp=sharing  . But the issue is that the pods continuosly go and back forth from Running to CrashLoopBackOff State :

Comment: Check the container logs:                  
kubectl logs -f arango-deployment-operator-5f4d66bd86-bgqbd -c operator
kubectl logs -f arango-storage-operator-5fcb46574-w2b6b -c operator

Comment: Thank you @R1w . But after many logs analysis I opened an issue in `kube-arangodb` GitHub Repo: https://github.com/arangodb/kube-arangodb/issues/1456

Comment: Nice job, it seems your problem is solved after all.

Comment: @R1w unfortunately it is not already solved. The issue in `kube-arangodb` is open and pending.

Comment: @R1w update: as you can see here : https://github.com/arangodb/kube-arangodb/issues/1456#issuecomment-1779310532 ArangoDB people think this is not a problem with the Arangodb Kubernetes operator, and closed my issue in GitHub Repo. The best way to solve an issue, is to not to consider it an issue to solve... is that funny?

Comment: Regrettably, I have been monitoring the problem you brought up on GitHub. When "dothebart" closed the issue, I assumed it had been resolved. Let's revisit the logs and conduct a thorough review. There have been instances where it took me a while to resolve certain cases, and some of them had significant consequences. Sometimes, you need to step away for a while and then return to reevaluate the logs and evidence once more.

Comment: I suggest a systematic approach to address the issue. First, thoroughly inspect each potentially problematic component independently. Consider this structured approach to address the issue. First, thoroughly inspect individual components. Ensure your code is error-free by testing it in a local Docker container. Afterward, recreate your Pods in a different environment for a fresh perspective. A comprehensive examination is crucial, but doing so in a distinct context can provide valuable insights.